# GET-Request: Fails

Tags: c#, networking, webclient, anglesharp

When trying to gather information from a website:

```
DefaultHttpRequester req = new DefaultHttpRequester();

req.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0";
 
IConfiguration config = Configuration.Default.With(req).WithDefaultLoader().WithDefaultCookies();

var afdas = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("https://www.wg-gesucht.de/api/profiles/contact-data/5520144?asset_type=0&asset_id=6839242").Result;
```

I got an ERROR-Message:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>{"type":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/Protocols\/rfc2616\/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Not Acceptable","status":406,"detail":"Cannot honor Accept type specified"}</body>
</html>
```

Based on the ERROR-Message:

> https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
>
> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating
> response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable
> according to the accept headers sent in the request.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity
> containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s)
> from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.
> The entity format is specified by the media type given in the
> Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the
> capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate
> choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification
> does not define any standard for such automatic selection.
>
> ```
>   Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are
>   not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the
>   request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a
>   406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of
>   an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.
> ```
>
> If the response could be unacceptable, a user agent SHOULD temporarily
> stop receipt of more data and query the user for a decision on further
> actions.

I have added all headers which could be seen in Firefox:

```
DefaultHttpRequester req = new DefaultHttpRequester();

req.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0";
req.Headers["Accept"] = "*/*"; // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept
req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, br";
req.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
req.Headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive";
req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "document";
req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "navigate";
req.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "cross-site";
req.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";
 
IConfiguration config = Configuration.Default.With(req).WithDefaultLoader().WithDefaultCookies();

var afdas = BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync("https://www.wg-gesucht.de/api/profiles/contact-data/5520144?asset_type=0&asset_id=6839242").Result;
```

But I still got the same error, so what did I do wrong?

Comment: There is a bug in the code it seems. Can you try with right config. For example `DefaultHttpRequester req = new DefaultHttpRequester();

            req.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0";

            IConfiguration Config = Configuration.Default.With(req).WithDefaultLoader().WithDefaultCookies();

            var afdas = BrowsingContext.New(Config).OpenAsync("https://www.wg-gesucht.de/api/profiles/contact-data/5520144?asset_type=0&asset_id=6839242").Result;
`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
DefaultHttpRequester req = new DefaultHttpRequester();

            req.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0";

            IConfiguration Config = Configuration.Default.With(req).WithDefaultLoader().WithDefaultCookies();

            var afdas = BrowsingContext.New(Config).OpenAsync("https://www.wg-gesucht.de/api/profiles/contact-data/5520144?asset_type=0&asset_id=6839242").Result;
```

Comment: I still got ("{"type":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/Protocols\/rfc2616\/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Not Acceptable","status":406,"detail":"Cannot honor Accept type specified"}") ... The response shoud be  [like this](https://www.wg-gesucht.de/api/profiles/contact-data/1501883?asset_type=0&asset_id=3579257), are you sure you get that response?